# Elastic Beanstalk deployments failing at AppDeployPreHook/12_update_permissions.sh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-efs

My EB deployments keep failing after spending 10-15 mins trying to deploy. Usually the log at eb-activity.log ends with this.

```
[2021-03-25T08:28:43.505Z] INFO  [1773]  - [Application update local-2021-03-25-a@121/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_update_permissions.sh] : Starting activity...
```

Sometimes it gets past this after about 15 mins, by which time EB has already given up and decided the deployment is bad.

```
[2021-03-25T08:43:33.853Z] INFO  [1773]  - [Application update local-2021-03-25-a@121/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_update_permissions.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user
  + EB_APP_USER=webapp
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_base_dir
  + EB_APP_BASE_DIR=/var/app
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_logs_dir
  + EB_APP_LOGS_DIR=/var/app/support/logs
  + cd /var/app/ondeck
  + chown -R webapp:webapp /var/app
  + chown -R webapp:webapp /var/log/httpd
  + '[' -f app/SymfonyRequirements.php ']'
```

Disk usage on the node is only about 30%. I have an attached EFS volume with about 90k files in it, mostly user data files. I suspect the permissions script is trying to update all of those files and taking too long.

But I don't know how to stop it, or if I can increase the time EB will wait for the deployment to succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked around this issue by extending the Command Timeout in the deployment config in EB. The default was 300 seconds.